# Double redux dispatch for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Every time I delete my useEffect and delete an item the action listResidents() runs twice for some reason, this is just one example this mostly happens even in other components, I don't know why it does that. I tried to solve it myself but ends up not dispatching every time I delete or do something.

```
function Residents() {
  const RESIDENT_COLUMNS = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'First Name',
        accessor: 'fname',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Last Name',
        accessor: 'lname',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'E-Mail',
        accessor: 'email',
        disableFilters: true,
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Phone',
        accessor: 'phone',
        disableFilters: true,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Blk',
        accessor: 'blk',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Lot',
        accessor: 'lot',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Street',
        accessor: 'street',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      {
        Header: 'Actions',
        accessor: 'actions',
        Cell: props => {
          return (
            <ButtonGroup spacing={2}>
              <IconButton
                colorScheme="blue"
                aria-label="Edit"
                icon={<EditIcon />}
                onClick={() => console.log(props.row.original._id)}
              />
              <IconButton
                colorScheme="red"
                aria-label="Edit"
                icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                onClick={() => deleteHandler(props.row.original._id)}
              />
            </ButtonGroup>
          );
        },
        disableFilters: true,
      },
    ],
    []
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const residentList = useSelector(state => state.residentList);
  const { loading, error, residents } = residentList;

  const residentDelete = useSelector(state => state.residentDelete);
  const { success: successDelete } = residentDelete;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listResidents());
  }, [dispatch, successDelete]);

  const columns = RESIDENT_COLUMNS;
  const data = useMemo(() => residents, [residents]);

  const deleteHandler = id => {
    dispatch(deleteResident(id));
  };

  return (
    <Box p="2rem 8rem">
      <ModalResident />
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message status="error">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <BaseTable data={data} columns={columns} />
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Residents;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `successDelete` changes back to false - maybe that's what happens when you dispatch listResidents()? - then that's why.

This will fix it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!successDelete) return;
    dispatch(listResidents());
  }, [dispatch, successDelete]);
```

^ EDIT: This **WON'T** fix it, because now you won't dispatch the `listResidents` on mount.

So, the effect is of a gross way to do dispatch `listResidents` after delete (but it's fine on mount). It's best to do it in the delete handler. Depending on if you're using `thunks` or not, you might be able to do this:

```
  const deleteHandler = async id => {
    await dispatch(deleteResident(id));
    dispatch(listResidents())
  };
```

and get rid of the `successDelete` dependency from the effect altogether.

Or, maybe just dispatch a `listResidents` in the thunk (again, if you are using thunks) that does the delete and keep it out of the component code altogether.

Comment: You mean I should go put the listResidents action inside the deleteResident action? But won't that just mean I can't dispatch the listResidents on mount/render

Comment: @kgcusi - depends what your `deleteResident` action looks like. That could be a way to go, again, if it is a thunk or thunk-like thing - you may want to dispatch a list residents action after the deleteResident action successfully completes. What does `deleteResident` look like?

Comment: This is my deleteResident, removed the `catch` block
`
export const deleteResident = id => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: RESIDENT_DELETE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/residents/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({
      type: RESIDENT_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: RESIDENT_DELETE_RESET,
    });
  }
`

Comment: So yeah, you can just throw a `dispatch(listResidents())` after your `RESIDENT_DELETE_RESET` and it will work. Make sure to remove `successDelete` from your `useEffect` dependency array.